# Circle-Circle Movement Collision

Tags: lua, constants, collision, geometry

How can i calculate collision between two moving circles in 2D space depending on time and describe it in lua function? Objects have their own constant speeds and start/end positions.
Function should look like this:

function Collision(s1, s2, e1, e2, v1, v2, r1, r2)
...
return true or false
end

s1, s2 - start position of obj 1,2

e1, e2 - end position of obj 1,2

v1, v2 - constant velocity of obj 1,2

r1, r2 - radius of obj 1,2

[Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ODGu.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :-). This website is not a coding service so please show us what you have tried.

Comment: distance between obj1 and obj2 lower than radius1 + radius2, but that is not what i need.

Comment: Are `s1` and `e1` 2D-vectors?  Are `v1` and `r1` numbers?

Comment: If the objects both start simultaneously and both stop simultaneously, then you don't need `v1` and `v2` arguments.

Comment: Are objects always move orthogonal paths?

Comment: Nevermind. I've already solved that while ago.